# How do I get the sum of a column across multiple keys?

Tags: mysql

I have data that looks like this:

```
id   int (11) primary key auto_increment
key  int (2)
type int (2)
data int (4)
timestamp datetime
```

There are 5 different keys - 1,2,3,4,5 and three types - 1,2,3

Data is put in continuously against a key and of a particular type.

What I need to extract is a sum of the data for a particular type (say, type 1) across all 5 keys (1,2,3,4,5) so it is a sum of exactly 5 records. I only want to sum the latest (max(timestamp) values (there are 5 of them) of data for each key, but they may all have different timestamps.

Something like this....

```
SELECT sum(data) FROM table WHERE type='1' AND timestamp=(SELECT max(timestamp FROM table WHERE type='1' GROUP BY key)
```

Or something like that. That isn't even close of course. I am completely lost on this one. it feels like I need to group by key but the syntax eludes me. Any suggestions are appreciated.

EDIT: additional info:

if:  'data' is temperature. 'key' is day of the week. 'type' is morning, noon or night

So the data might look like

```
morning  mon       70  (timestamp)
noon     tue       78  (timestamp)
morning  wed       72  (timestamp)
night    tue       74  (timestamp)
morning  thu       76  (timestamp)
noon     wed       77  (timestamp)
night    fri       78  (timestamp)
noon     tue       79  (timestamp)
```

If these are in timestamp order (desc) and I want the sum of most recent noon temps for all five days, the result would be: 155 in this case since the last noon was also tuesday and it was earlier and thus, not included. Make sense? I want sum of 'data' for any key, specific type, latest timestamp only. In this example, I would be summing at most 7 pieces of data.

Comment: I'm sorry Doug, this is not totally clear. Could you simply edit your question to provide a (short - but significant) sample of data as well as the expected result?

Comment: if timestamp is not unique, i.e. you can have two entries at the same second, it might get a bit tricky. Or a solution that works now will be dead then.

Comment: timestamp will always be unique for each key/type/timestamp combination meaning, in the example above, you will never see two rows with the same day and time of day on the same timestamp.

Comment: Be really, really careful if your timestamp-column is the automatic "timestamp" datatype. Change/correcture of any value updates that, and furthermore: as soon as you change the table-structure all your timestamps are "now()". No problem if it is a datetime-column. And if the datetime is that of measurement, not of processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `timestamp` column is guaranteed to be unique for each (`key`,`type`)  (That is, there's a UNIQUE constraint `ON (key,type,timestamp)`, then this query will return the specified resultset. (This isn't the only approach, but it is a familiar pattern):

```
SELECT SUM(t.data) AS latest_total
  FROM mytable t
  JOIN ( SELECT h.type
              , h.key
              , MAX(h.timestamp) AS max_ts
           FROM mytable h
          WHERE h.type='1'
          GROUP
             BY h.type
              , h.key
       ) m
    ON m.type = t.type
   AND m.key = t.key
   AND m.max_ts = t.timestamp
```

The inline view assigned an alias of `m` returns the "latest" `timestamp` for type=1 for all 5 key values (if at least one row exists)

That is joined to the original table, to retrieve the row that has that "latest" timestamp.

A suitable index with leading columns of `type`,`key`,`timestamp` will likely improve performance.

(That's based on my understanding of the specification; I may not be totally clear on the specification.  What this query is doing is getting the latest timestamp for the `type=1` rows. If there happen to be two (or more) rows with the same latest timestamp value for a given key and type, this query will retrieve both (or all) of those rows, and include them in the sum.

We could add a `GROUP BY t.type` on that query, and that wouldn't change the result, since we are guaranteed that the t.type will be equal to the constant 1 (specified in the predicate in the WHERE clause of the inline view query.)

But we would need to add the GROUP BY if we wanted to get totals for all three type in the same query:

```
SELECT t.key
     , SUM(t.data) AS latest_total
  FROM mytable t
  JOIN ( SELECT h.type
              , h.key
              , MAX(h.timestamp) AS max_ts
           FROM mytable h
          WHERE h.type IN ('1','2','3')
          GROUP
             BY h.type
              , h.key
       ) m
    ON m.type = t.type
   AND m.key = t.key
   AND m.max_ts = t.timestamp
 GROUP
    BY t.key
```

**NOTE:**

Using reserved words as identifiers (e.g. `TIMESTAMP` and `KEY` isn't illegal, but those identifiers (usually) need to be enclosed in backticks. But changing the names of these columns so that they aren't reserved words is best practice.

Comment: Thanks. Those are samples, not the real column names. :) I'll try this.

Comment: Beware of the "timestamp"- data format, if the values are that important. Use datetime and fill in the measurement-time.

Comment: of course. :) this is a sample. I used the term to illustrate it's function.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(data)
FROM ( SELECT CONCAT(MAX(timestamp), '_', type) AS customId
       FROM table
       WHERE type = '1'
       GROUP BY key ) a
JOIN table b ON a.customId = CONCAT(b.timestamp, '_', type)
GROUP BY type;
```

This would probably do the trick...

[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7c3f/8/0)

Comment: **N.B.** The predicate on the concatenation cannot make use of an index for a range scan, which can be a source of performance problems with this query on large sets.

Comment: You're right. I've already given you a +1 on your answer above.

Comment: +1 I just added that as a note about peformance concerns for future readers. But this approach would return the specified resultset, since we "know" that timestamp will not contain an underscore, there's no chance that the concatenation will produce an ambiguous value. (In the more general case, we might not have a guarantee, consider: "`CONCAT('a_','_','b' = CONCAT('a','_','_b')`"

Answer (score 0):

I would for simplicity and maintainability use a temp-table and fill it with several statements. The solution with "union-subselect" looks a bit long for me.

So

```
   drop tamporary table if exists tmp_data;

   create temporary table tmp_data (type int, value int);
   insert into tmp_data select 1, value from data_table where type=1 order by timestamp desc limit 5;
   insert into tmp_data select 2, value from data_table where type=2 order by timestamp desc limit 5;
   insert into tmp_data select 3, value from data_table where type=3 order by timestamp desc limit 5;

   select type, sum(value) as total from tmp_data group by type;
```

EDIT:
The subselect-solution would be similar, and since there are only 3 types not too bad

```
  select type, sum(value) as total from 
       (select 1 as type, value from data_table where type=1 order by timestamp desc limit 5
        union
        select 2 as type, value from data_table where type=2 order by timestamp desc limit 5
        union
        select 3 as type, value from data_table where type=3 order by timestamp desc limit 5) as subtab group by type;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The query would sum up the value for the 5 "latest" rows for each given type. Aside from possibility of the UNION operator eliminating duplicate values (i think those should really be `UNION ALL` operators, this approach works, but I don't think this is the resultset the OP specified. I think he wanted to add up the values from the latest row `type=1,key=1`, the latest row for `type=1,key=2`. To meet the spec, this query could UNION ALL 15 queries (`WHERE type=1 AND key=1`, `WHERE type=1 AND key=2`) and get just the latest row from each (`ORDER BY timestamp LIMIT 1`).

Comment: If a suitable index is available, and if `ORDER BY type DESC, key DESC, timestamp DESC LIMIT 1` gets optimized so that the latest row is returned quickly using the index (avoiding an expensive filesort operation on every row), this approach may be faster than the query in my answer.

Comment: @spencer7593: you are right, in the original question the timestamp played a greater role, so I understood he wanted the latest 5. Your solution would bring strange values as soon as two rows for a key-type get inserted/updated at the same second.  The union can remove duplicate rows only if 1 = 2 or 2=3 or 1=3, since "type" is a part of the select. ;-)

Comment: which is exactly why my answer starts with "If the timestamp column is guaranteed to be unique for each (key,type) ..."

Comment: Just to be clear, there IS an issue with the UNION operator in your query. It doesn't just remove duplicates between the sets, but within the sets as well. If the query that gets the `type=2` rows happens to return 2 or more rows that have the same `value`, the duplicate `value` will be eliminated. (No indication is given that there is a guarantee that the `value` isn't repeated.)